Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 512 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
Tried Box to add Account State data on heap on build
Anchor Version: 0.28.0
Solana-cli Version: 1.18.25
Error: Function _ZN112_$LT$solana_program..instruction..InstructionError$u20$as$u20$solana_frozen_abi..abi_example..AbiEnumVisitor$GT$13visit_for_abi17h39952282aec2bd99E Stack offset of 4608 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 512 bytes, please minimize large stack variables
declare_id!("H3jJR4g9m3Q8HGFagfAsdubqJTXHiMChZi4G5JdpjGtt");

#[program]
pub mod readmint {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_book(ctx: Context<CreateBook>, title: String, _aname: String) -> Result<()> {
        let book = &mut ctx.accounts.book;
        book.author = ctx.accounts.author.key();
        book.total_pages = 0;
        book.title = title;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(title: String, aname: String)]
pub struct CreateBook<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub author: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = author,
        space = 8 + Book::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [title.as_bytes(), aname.as_bytes()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub book: Box<Account<'info, Book>>,
}

#[account]
#[derive(InitSpace)]
pub struct Book {
    pub author: Pubkey,
    #[max_len(32)]
    pub title: String,
    pub total_pages: u32,
}```



This question is similar to: 'please minimize large stack variables' error on building hello_world. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
